# How to know the objectGUID of a user that successfully authenticated with LDAP bind

Tags: php, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I have:

- a PHP application on a linux server
- a (windows server 2012) domain controller

I want to make it possible for AD users to log in the PHP application. The PHP application will associate data to the user, so i need to create the user in my database.

When a new user is created in the PHP application, the administrator chooses from a list of the userPrincipalName of the AD users. When a userPrincipalName is chosen, the PHP gets the objectGUID of this user and stores it in the database. Indeed, as the UPN could change, i can not rely on that to uniquely identify the user. Also, i want that if the UPN changes, the user can sill log in seamlessly to the PHP application, with his new UPN.

When a user wants to log in my application, the PHP receives a username and a password, and pass them to ldap_bind to check if the credentials are valid. The problem at that point is that ldap bind gives no clue of what user he actually identified (ldap_bind has a complicated logic of validating a login/password (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223499.aspx)).

The most atomic (and hence, reliable) way of doing it would be if ldap bind was returning the objectGUID... But it doesn't, and i won't code the logic of ldap bind in PHP to find which user he has actually identified (it would be buggy anyway because of race condition if the directory change between the ldap bind and my "manual" search)

So what should i do to authenticate AND identify the LDAP user from PHP, if possible, in a single request to the domain controller (to get atomicity) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point in the process you need to have logic that searches for the UPN being used for the username in the login, obtain its objectGuid, and search for that objectGuid in the database. There is no other way to get that information.

If you're worried about a potential race condition (which seems like quite the edge case, given the timing between the bind and the search would be extremely tight), you could use a separate AD service account that searches for the account by UPN prior to the bind. Then in the `ldap_bind` for checking the user's credentials you could even use the objectGuid from the account you searched for to do the login, as that's a valid "username" for an AD bind (the GUID with curly braces around it that is).

Comment: Yes that's what i did finally, first step get the GUID by UPN, then bind (this forces the user to enter a UPN though, which is more restrictive than what bind permits). But your idea of using the GUID to bind seems more secure than using the UPN again (which i did), so thanks ! I know it's edge case but i wanted to be sure to not miss something in the LDAP API, because it looked obvious to me that many app would have the same problem.

Comment: I'd FIRST do a search for the user with the given "username" to get the users DN and use that THEN to do the bind. For the search I'd bind with a defined user with search-capabilities. That would then also work with other LDAP-backends as it doesn't rely on ADs ability to bind with a UPN. During that search you can also retrieve the objectGUID so there shouldn't be a race-condition anymore. Added benefit: depending on the used search-filter you can also use your email-address or telephone number or whatever you like to log in ;)

Comment: @heiglandreas If it's for an application being developed to support a wider audience I'd probably agree. But if it's an internally developed application and they use AD then there's no issue using one of the other supported username methods for a bind, especially if it better fits their use case. A DN can change, an objectGuid cannot. I actually think the additional bind formats supported by AD is a benefit over implementations like OpenLDAP (which I'm surprised there isn't a module or add on to allow this sort of behavior).

Comment: @ChadSikorra: The change in the DN doesn't matter as the objectGUID is still used to connect to the DB-stored user. It's only used for the authentication against the LDAP instead of the UPN. In the end it's what you suggested in the second paragraph (which I seemed to have misread) only using the returned DN for the bind instead of the objectGUID. But as you have the objectGUID at hand then, you can then use that to retrieve the user from the database.